# How do I connect React native app with node js?

Tags: node.js, react-native, react-redux

I have already created backend using node js for sigin & signup page. Now I want to connect to node js . But i have no idea how to do that. I want to connect both react native with my node js. Can you help me ?

Comment: I'm not exactly sure with what you meant by 'connect'. However, I presume you refer to having your react native be able to interact with your node js backend server and exchange data? To do that, you just have to simply call your node js endpoint; example `http://localhost:4000`, by using either `fetch` command, or `Axios`. Refer to these documentations to learn more --> https://reactnative.dev/docs/network (Fetch), https://www.npmjs.com/package/axios (Axios).

Comment: `Axios` is an NPM library that handles http request.

Answer (score 0):

simply as how we do for web apps.

here is an example of error reporting

```js
export default async function (body) {
  console.log(JSON.stringify(body))
  const res = await fetch(`${host}/api/report`, {
    method: 'POST',
    body: JSON.stringify(body),
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    },
  })

  const { message } = await res.json()
  if (message) return Toast({ message: message });
  else return Toast({ message: 'network error' });
}
```

I have used `fetch` to send a POST request to my nodejs server

use API tool like postman or other and make your your nodejs APIs works fine and then connect to your React Native app as above.

Answer (score 0):

You can use *ngrok* to connect Node with react-native. Run this command:

```sh
npm i ngrok -g # installing it globally
```

Then open another terminal. Run:

```sh
ngrok http 3000 # the port you are running on node
```

Then it will show an alternative link that you can use to test with your Node.
**Note:** if `ngrok http 3000` doesn't work, try `ngrok http -region us 3000`.
The available ones are `us`, `eu`, `ap`, and `au`. In my case eu worked for me.

Then copy the link generated e.g. `http://8074-129-205-124-100.eu.ngrok.io` and test your backend if it displays APIs.

If the link works then you can use it with [`fetch`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch). Uploading json data to send to MongoDB as the case maybe.